# cloudinary upload vuejs Wait until complete

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, promise, cloudinary

i'm uploading an array of images to cloudinary and i need to save the response.secure_url in my database alongside other properties for my datas but the program don't await for the response and continue.

```
uploadFileToCloudinary:function (file,indexImg,self=this) {
            return new Promise ((resolve,reject)=>{                 
                //doit tracer la progression de l'upload des images : done
                
                const CLOUDINARY_URL = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloudinary-appdatas/upload'
                const CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET = 'xxxxxxxxx'
            
                let formData = new FormData()
                formData.append('upload_preset',CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_PRESET)
                formData.append('folder','montures')
                formData.append('file',file)

                let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('POST',CLOUDINARY_URL,true)
                request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest')

                request.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                    console.log('progress ',indexImg,': ', e.loaded)
                    self.pourcentageComplete[indexImg] = Math.ceil((e.loaded / e.total)*100)
                    console.log("pourcentageComplete",self.pourcentageComplete[indexImg])
                }
                
                request.onreadystatechange = () => {
                // File uploaded successfully
                    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status ===200) {
                        let response = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
                        //Reste encore a enregister le lien response.url dans l'api
                        resolve(response)
                    }
                // Not succesfull, let find out what happened
                    if (request.status !== 200) {
                        let response = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
                        let error = response.error.message
                        alert('error, status != 200 : '+ error)
                        reject(error)
                    }
                }
                request.onerror = (err) =>{
                    alert('error : '+ err)
                    reject(err)
                }
                request.send(formData)
            })
        }
```

here's where i call the function

```
if (this.images.length > 4){
                alert("⚠ Maximum 4 images autorisées !⚠")
                return ; // trop d'image : on sort de la boucle
            } else {
                this.images.forEach((image,index) => { 
                // faire en sorte que la chaque iteration attende la fin de l'execution avant passer a la suivante
                    this.uploadFileToCloudinary(image,index,this)
                    .then((response) =>{
                        // if(response){
                        console.log('image ',index,' uploadée avec succes')
                        this.pourcentageComplete[index] = 100
                        // }
                        // console.log('response after an upload : ',response)
                        this.cloud_image.push(response.secure_url)

                    })
                    .catch((err) =>{
                        console.log('error upload to cloudinary:',err)
                    })
                    .finally(()=>{
                        console.log('iteration:',index)
                        // console.log('liens cloudinary at the end:' , this.cloud_image)
                    })
                })

                this.$store.dispatch('moduleMonture/addMonture',payload)
```

the payload is the object containing cloud_image (array of the links for the cloudinary images i uploaded) and the other products properties

I hope I managed to make myself understood because English is not my native language

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The `forEachAsync()` functor is missing a `return`.

Comment: Always `reject()` with an Error object, not String.

Comment: Are you sure you want to run `this.$store.dispatch()` without awaiting completion of the image uploads? As written, that's what will happen.

Comment: Actually, i want `this.store.dispatch()` to await the upload completion before running